# How to do the undo and redo operations in the InkCanvas UWP?

Tags: uwp, inkcanvas

I want to do the Undo and Redo operations in the InkCanvas. How to do it?

how to get the strokes on the PointerReleasing. I have tried the code

```
path = new InkCanvas()
        {
            Height = mImageEditor.imageEditorPanel.ActualHeight,
            Width = mImageEditor.imageEditorPanel.ActualWidth
        };
        CoreInkIndependentInputSource core = CoreInkIndependentInputSource.Create(path.InkPresenter);
        core.PointerReleasing += Core_PointerReleasing;

        path.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse 
                                            | Windows.UI.Core.CoreInputDeviceTypes.Touch;
        InkDrawingAttributes inkDrawingAttributes = new InkDrawingAttributes();
        inkDrawingAttributes.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Blue;
        inkDrawingAttributes.Size = new Size(8, 8);
        path.InkPresenter.UpdateDefaultDrawingAttributes(inkDrawingAttributes);
        var value = path.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes();
        this.Children.Add(path);
```

I am getting this exception, so i can't able to get the strokes on pointer releasing event.
[image]

How to do the Undo and Redo operations? Anyone please suggest me.

Comment: You can find a sample [here](https://github.com/ashchuk/UWPImageEditor). It's Win2D sample, but I think it will be the same in your case too

Comment: Thanks for your sample. It is useful for me. But I am confusing why I am getting these exceptions.